# Docker CE on premises with private repository: possible?

Tags: docker, dtr

I am wondering if it is possible to setup Docker CE on premises with a private repository (using DTR engine or other alternative if they exist)? My company has some strict rules to not have things in the cloud...

I know this is possible with the EE version but I would like to start with the CE version for a few months to see if it will work in our environment.

Comment: You can specify where to pull images from.  See [pulling from a different registry](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to your question:

- deploying a registry itself
- configuring docker engine instances to access the registry

For deploying the registry all you need to do is deploy it as answered by @sony vizio and outlined here https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-a-local-registry

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

For configuring your docker engines to access this registry you will need to add `insecture-registries` to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (provided the above deployment took place on host `registry`):

```
{
  "insecure-registries": ["registry:5000"]
}
```

Images that you push to your local registry will need to be tagged with the registry `host:port`:

```
docker tag myimage registry:5000/myimage
docker push registry:5000/myimage
```

and then elsewhere

```
docker run registry:5000/myimage
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`

[docker reg server](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-a-local-registry)